# REST-запросы на сайт на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, json

Каким образом можно обработать REST-запрос в wordpress?

Comment: Не уверен что правильно понял, но мб будет полезно https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На WordPress сервере надо вставить такой обработчик в `function.php`:

```
function reply() {
    if ( isset($_POST['smthing']) ) {  // проверяем, задан ли параметр POST smthing
        $smthing = $_POST['smthing'];  // берем его значение
        $smthing = json_decode($smthing);  // декодируем json
        if ($smthing->type == 'good') {  // если тип в json = 'good' (ну, типа, хороший запрос)
            wp_send_json_success('Answer to good request');  // посылаем назад json с правильным сообщением 
        }
        else {
            wp_send_json_error();  // иначе - просто посылаем ))
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'reply' );  // так в WP добавляется хук на этапе инициализации
```

Поскольку срабатывать он будет на довольно раннем этапе, а wp_send_json... завершает выполнение (как и die() ), то работать код будет достаточно эффективно.

Насчет быстродействия. [Вот тут](https://support.tigertech.net/wordpress-performance) пишут, что добились на WordPress 1700 просмотров страниц в секунду. Код в примере выше (при равном железе) будет работать существенно быстрее, потому что нет даже вызова плагина для отдачи кешированной страницы.

Общие рекомендации по разработке высоконагруженных систем на WordPress можно [найти тут](https://codex.wordpress.org/High_Traffic_Tips_For_WordPress).

Comment: да, примерно. Добавил в код декодирование json и комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать, как вы написали. Я точно так же пишу все обработчики почты, так ими легко управлять (как файлом обычным на серваке). Обычно я кладу обработчики в корень темы.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/theme/mailer.php',
    data: msg,
    success: function(){
        console.log("thx");
        jQuery('#form-result').modal('show');
    },
    error: function(xhr, str){
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }}
);
```